# dice combination probability from 6 to 9 dice (like Yahtzee with more dices)

Tags: probability

I have a question about how can I calculate dice combination probability from 6 to 9 dices. I came across this picture on the following [website](http://datagenetics.com/blog/january42012/index.html) which is based on the Yahtzee game:

[image: 1]

Now it would be great to have this calculations or this table for 6 to 9 dices. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with stochastic or this higher math.

Can someone help me here? Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 6 to 9 dices? As in, we are using 6 to 9 dice instead of 5?

Comment: Correct. So instead of using 5 dices. How is the probability with 6 to 9 dices. @InterstellarProbe already did it

Comment: Yet again: "Dices" is a verb meaning to cut something into small cubes (used primarily in recipes).  As a noun "Dice" is itself the plural of the singular "die".  You mean "6 to 9 dice" NOT "6 to 9 dices".

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry so as you already guess correctly I mean "6 to 9 dice"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With 6 dice:

AAAAAA - Choose the number to be repeated in $\dbinom{6}{1} = 6$ ways. Total probability:
$$\dbinom{6}{1}\dfrac{1}{6^6} = \dfrac{6}{46,656}$$

AAAAAB - Choose the two numbers in $\dbinom{6}{2} = 15$ ways. Choose which of the two numbers is repeated five times in $2$ ways. Choose the order of the rolls in $\dbinom{6}{1} = 6$ ways. Total probability: $$\dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{6}{1}\dfrac{1}{6^6} = \dfrac{180}{46,656}$$

AAAABB - Choose the two numbers in $\dbinom{6}{2} = 15$ ways. Choose which of the two numbers is repeated four times in $2$ ways. Choose the order of the rolls in $\dbinom{6}{2} = 15$ ways. Total probability: $$\dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{6}{2}\dfrac{1}{6^6} = \dfrac{450}{46,656}$$

AAAABC - Choose the three numbers in $\dbinom{6}{3} = 20$ ways. Choose one of the three numbers to be repeated four times in $\dbinom{3}{1} = 3$ ways. Choose the order of the rolls in $\dfrac{6!}{4!1!1!} = 30$ ways. Total probability: $$\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{3}{1}\dfrac{6!}{4!1!1!} = \dfrac{1,800}{46,656}$$

AAABBB - Choose the two numbers in $\dbinom{6}{2} = 15$ ways. Choose both of the numbers to be repeated three times in $\dbinom{2}{2} = 1$ way. Choose the order of the rolls in $\dfrac{6!}{3!3!} = 20$ ways. Total probability: $$\dfrac{300}{46,656}$$

AAABBC - Choose the three numbers in $\dbinom{6}{3} = 20$ ways. Order the numbers by how many times they will be repeated in $3!$ ways. Choose the order of the rolls in $\dfrac{6!}{3!2!1!} = 60$ ways. Total probability: $$\dfrac{7,200}{46,656}$$

AAABCD - Choose the four numbers in $\dbinom{6}{4} = 15$ ways. Choose one of the numbers to be repeated three times in $\dbinom{4}{1}=4$ ways. Choose the order of the numbers in $\dfrac{6!}{3!1!1!1!} = 120$ ways. Total probability: $$\dfrac{7,200}{46,656}$$

AABBCC - Choose the three numbers in $\dbinom{6}{3} = 20$ ways. Each number is repeated twice in $\dbinom{3}{3} = 1$ way. Choose the order of the rolls in $\dfrac{6!}{2!2!2!} = 90$ ways. Total probability: $$\dfrac{1,800}{46,656}$$

AABBCD - Choose the four numbers in $\dbinom{6}{4} = 15$ ways. Choose two numbers to be repeated twice (the other two are automatically repeated once each) in $\dbinom{4}{2}=6$ ways. Choose the order in $\dfrac{6!}{2!2!1!1!} = 180$ ways. Total probability: $$\dfrac{16,200}{46,656}$$

AABCDE - Choose the five numbers in $\dbinom{6}{5} = 6$ ways. Choose the number to be repeated (the other four numbers are all automatically repeated once each) in $\dbinom{5}{1} = 5$ ways. Choose the order in $\dfrac{6!}{2!1!1!1!1!} = 360$ ways. Total probability: $$\dfrac{10,800}{46,656}$$

ABCDEF - Choose the six numbers in $\dbinom{6}{6} = 1$ way. Choose the six numbers to be repeated once each in $\dbinom{6}{6} = 1$ way. Choose the order in $6!=720$ ways. Total probability: $$\dfrac{720}{46,656}$$

To ensure this covers the total probability space, we add it all up:

$$\dfrac{6+180+450+1,800+300+7,200+7,200+1,800+16,200+10,800+720}{46,656} = \dfrac{46,656}{46,656} = 100\%$$

7 dice:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Pattern} & \text{Probability} \\ \hline AAAAAAA & \dfrac{6}{279,936} \\ AAAAAAB & \dfrac{210}{279,936} \\ AAAAABB & \dfrac{630}{279,936} \\ AAAAABC & \dfrac{2,520}{279,936} \\ AAAABBB & \dfrac{1,050}{279,936} \\ AAAABBC & \dfrac{12,600}{279,936} \\ AAAABCD & \dfrac{12,600}{279,936} \\ AAABBBC & \dfrac{8,400}{279,936} \\ AAABBCC & \dfrac{12,600}{279,936} \\ AAABBCD & \dfrac{75,600}{279,936} \\ AAABCDE & \dfrac{25,200}{279,936} \\ AABBCCD & \dfrac{37,800}{279,936} \\ AABBCDE & \dfrac{75,600}{279,936} \\ AABCDEF & \dfrac{15,120}{279,936}\end{array}$$

8 dice - Denominator is $6^8 = 1,679,616$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Pattern} & \text{Numerator} \\ \hline AAAAAAAA & 6 \\ AAAAAAAB & 240 \\ AAAAAABB & 840 \\ AAAAAABC & 3,360 \\ AAAAABBB & 1,680 \\ AAAAABBC & 20,160 \\ AAAAABCD & 20,160 \\ AAAABBBB & 1,050 \\ AAAABBBC & 33,600 \\ AAAABBCC & 25,200 \\ AAAABBCD & 151,200 \\ AAAABCDE & 50,400 \\ AAABBBCC & 33,600 \\ AAABBBCD & 100,800 \\ AAABBCCD & 302,400 \\ AAABBCDE & 403,200 \\ AAABCDEF & 40,320 \\ AABBCCDD & 37,800 \\ AABBCCDE & 302,400 \\ AABBCDEF & 151,200\end{array}$$

9 dice - Denominator is $6^9 = 10,077,696$:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Pattern} & \text{Numerator} \\ \hline AAAAAAAAA & 6 \\ AAAAAAAAB & 270 \\ AAAAAAABB & 1,080 \\ AAAAAAABC & 4,320 \\ AAAAAABBB & 2,520 \\ AAAAAABBC & 30,240 \\ AAAAAABCD & 30,240 \\ AAAAABBBB & 3,780 \\ AAAAABBBC & 60,480 \\ AAAAABBCC & 45,360 \\ AAAAABBCD & 272,160 \\ AAAAABCDE & 90,720 \\ AAAABBBBC & 37,800 \\ AAAABBBCC & 151,200 \\ AAAABBBCD & 453,600 \\ AAAABBCCD & 680,400 \\ AAAABBCDE & 907,200 \\ AAAABCDEF & 90,720 \\ AAABBBCCC & 33,600 \\ AAABBBCCD & 907,200 \\ AAABBBCDE & 604,800 \\ AAABBCCDD & 453,600 \\ AAABBCCDE & 2,721,600 \\ AAABBCDEF & 907,200 \\ AABBCCDDE & 680,400 \\ AABBCCDEF & 907,200\end{array}$$

Edit: I fixed the table for 8 dice.

Comment: How could you manage to answer this question in 2 hours?! You're awesome! Thanks

Comment: It helps that I enjoy combinatorial mathematics ;-) But thank you!